# Is replacing the prototype of a built-in function illegal?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```js
Date.prototype = { foo : 1 };
Date.prototype.foo // => null
```

It's odd that replacing the prototype of a built-in function simply gets ignored without any error issued, yet I couldn't find any articles, books, or blog posts mentioning it.

Comment: There's nothing illegal about it, although you should avoid doing it. Modifying built-in objects prototypes is how many polyfills work.

Comment: You can't reassign `Date.prototype`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype though you can modify the object it references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not illegal (in that the specification doesn't prevent you doing it). It's commonly done on functions you define yourself.

It's ignored on the functions defined by the JavaScript specification because their `prototype` property is *read-only*. From [the specification for `Date.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype):

> The initial value of Date.prototype is the intrinsic object %DatePrototype% (20.3.4).
>
> This property has the attributes { **[[Writable]]: false**, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

*(My emphasis.)*

Assigning to it is only *silently* ignored in loose mode; in strict mode (which we should all be using basically all the time), it's an error:

```js
"use strict";
Date.prototype = {};
```

---

Going a bit beyond the question, you can define your *own* read-only properties that behave the same way, if you like, via `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "answer", {
    value: 42,
    writable: false // This is for emphasis, it's actually the default
});
tryLoose();
tryStrict();
function tryLoose() {
    console.log("Trying to assign new value in loose mode.");
    obj.answer = "It's complicated.";
    console.log("After assignment, obj.answer = " + obj.answer);
}
function tryStrict() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Trying to assign new value in strict mode.");
    obj.answer = "It's complicated.";
    console.log("We won't get here.");
}
```

Comment: Yes, the prototype is frozen (i.e. read only) on built in js objects. You can check this by using your browser's inspector and (in firefox) seeing if there a padlock next to a property.

Comment: @tanenbring: Ah, I get it now. How did I miss the padlock thing when reading this morning?

Answer (score 1):

It's like Russian Roulette. Illegal? No. Will you shoot yourself? Maybe.

Pretty much everything in javascript consists of keys and values, including built-ins, which can be reassigned without any warning or error given. Though there will likely be unintended side-effects -- if not in your code, then in some library you're using.

Comment: Well, the OP's example (`Date.prototype`) can't be reassigned on compliant browser, as it's read-only...

Comment: Matter of fact, there are several things that are allowed in javascript like this. For example you can redefine `undefined`

Comment: @element11 You *could* redefine `undefined`

Comment: @element11 As in it's not possible anymore.

Comment: javascript and russian roulette, sometimes do indeed appear as if it's the same thing. one of them will torture you over and over again instead of once though

Answer (score 0):

Every property of any object in JavaScript has defined descriptor: is it `writable`, `enumerable`, `configurable`. Property `prototype` of `Date` object is not writable, therefore you cannot change its value.

You can convince yourself that `prototype` of `Date` is non-writable by running:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Date, 'prototype')
```

This will return object which has `writable` set to `false`.